# how to find if youtube url is channel or playlist in java

Tags: javascript, java, youtube

I have multiple YouTube URL's. How can I find if the URL is a playlist or a channel in Java?

I am able to find if a YouTube url is a video by finding `v` parameter of the url, if the url doesn't have `v` parameter, I am considering it as not a video. 
Is there any process in the same way to find if the url is a channel or a playlist?

Comment: Well, channel URLs have `channel` in them, playlist URL have `playlist` in it, if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every URL with channel is different from playlist
channel URL have "**channel**"
https://www.youtube.com/**channel**/UCFPS0qKgr-GbSRAppOkdpUA

so using URL String find also you can check if URL is Channel or not.

Playlist URL does not have /channel/ word

Answer (score 0):

The Url should have a different pattern which you can check like youtube.com/c/... for channels , scan the URL for that pattern then execute your code.